# Meaning of the ending “‑exia”?

Tags: meaning, etymology, suffixes, latin, greek

If a word ends in *-exia* (such as *dyslexia*, *anorexia*, and *pyrexia*), does this imply anything about the word itself?

For example, in electronics a word ending in *‑ance* (such as *impedance* or *resistance*) means the word is related to a property of the component in the circuit.

Does anything similar hold for *‑exia*?

Comment: Identifying the last four letters here does not seem too helpful, as sumelic points out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misconception.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  What misconception? It sounds a perfectly reasonable enough question to me. If you are going to close such things as this, what will there be left?

Comment: They needed to name a bunch of diseases and all the other suffixes were taken.

Comment: @WS2 To quote sumelic, 'The words "dyslexia" and "anorexia" actually don't have the -exia suffix, although they end in the same letters and they do refer to disorders.' OP could have easily found the etymologies of dyslexia and anorexia himself.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If we are going to be that strict about it, almost any question posed here, could be answered if enough painstaking research were done. Whilst I agree that there are far too many instances where people simply ask something like 'how does *diarrhoea* differ from *dysentery*; when all they need do is look the two words up in a dictionary. Clearly those merit closure, but in this case the question does present an interesting topic for discussion.

Comment: @WS2 I agree. But the question needs amending.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How would you suggest amending it?

Comment: It's too late now; sumelic's 'one-by-one etymological information' was easy to find and could have been given as research done. Josh's material is perhaps not so easy to discover.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> If a word ends in -exia, such as dyslexia, anorexia and pyrexia does
>   this imply anything about the word itself?

It doesn't *necessarily* imply something about the word.
[Josh61's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/268646/77227) (which you should read, and which I won't copy here) gives an excellent explanation of the suffix "-exia," used in the word "[pyrexia](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pyrexia&searchmode=none)" and also for some other medical conditions like "cachexia."

But, it is important to keep in mind that sometimes words end in the same sounds by coincidence, rather than because they share a suffix.

The words "dyslexia" and "anorexia" actually don't have the -exia suffix, although they end in the same letters and they do refer to disorders.

It appears that the "suffix" proper that these words have in common is simply [-ia](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ia&allowed_in_frame=0). It comes after the noun stem orex- (meaning "appetite") in [anorexia](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=anorexia&allowed_in_frame=0), and after the noun stem "lex-" (meaning "speech, word") in [dyslexia](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dyslexia&searchmode=none).

But, both of these noun stems are derived from verb roots using the common nominalizing suffix [-s(is)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%CF%83%CE%B9%CF%82#Ancient_Greek). So "orexis" = "oreg.sis," from the verb "orego" ("reach"), and "lexis" = "leg.sis," from the verb "lego" ("speak").

So, you could view the above two words as sharing a sort of "compound suffix" "-s.ia". But in both cases, the "e" and the first part of the "x" belong to the root rather than to the suffix.

---

Here's one-by-one etymological information:

"anorexia" word origin according to [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/anorexia?q=anorexia):

> via late Latin from Greek, from an- ‘without’ + orexis ‘appetite’.

"anorexia" on [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=anorexia&allowed_in_frame=0):

> 1590s, "lack of appetite," Modern Latin, from Greek anorexia, from
>   an-, privative prefix, "without" (see an- (1)) + orexis "appetite,
>   desire," from oregein "to desire, stretch out" (cognate with Latin
>   regere "to keep straight, guide, rule;" see regal) + abstract noun
>   ending -ia. In current use, often short for anorexia nervosa.

"orexis" (ὄρεξις) etymology according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%84%CF%81%CE%B5%CE%BE%CE%B9%CF%82#Ancient_Greek):

> From ὀρέγω ‎(orégō, “I stretch”) +‎ -σις ‎(-sis).

"dyslexia" word origin according to [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dyslexia?q=dyslexia):

> from "dys- ‘difficult’ + Greek lexis ‘speech'

"dyslexia" on [Etymonline](http://c.%201887,%20from%20German%20dyslexie%20(1883),%20from%20Greek%20dys-%20%22bad,%20abnormal,%20difficult%22%20(see%20dys-)%20+%20lexis%20%22word,%22%20from%20legein%20%22speak%22%20(see%20lecture%20(n.))%20+%20abstract%20noun%20ending%20-ia.%20Dyslexic%20(n.)%20is%20first%20recorded%201961;%20dyslectic%20(adj.)%20from%201964.):

> c. 1887, from German dyslexie (1883), from Greek dys- "bad, abnormal,
>   difficult" (see dys-) + lexis "word," from legein "speak" (see lecture
>   (n.)) + abstract noun ending -ia. Dyslexic (n.) is first recorded
>   1961; dyslectic (adj.) from 1964.

Presumably the same suffix "-sis" was used here, though neither Etymonline nor Wiktionary say this explicitly.

origin of "pyrexia" according to [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pyrexia):

> New Latin, from Greek pyressein to be feverish, from pyrites

Comment: This breakdown works just as well for _pyrexia_ and _cachexia_, actually: the suffix _-exia_ in those is also just a compound suffix, made up of _-(h)ech-_ ‘have’ + _-si-_ + _-ia_. The only difference is that those have an extra element that ends in a velar after the root, instead of just having a root that ends in a velar.

Comment: Also, sometimes the "coincidence" is somewhat intentional. If there were other conditions that ended in _exia_, the coiner of _dislexia_ may have chosen to use the root _lex_ to parallel that construction. This choice could also have been subconscious.

Answer (score 15):

***[-exia](http://SuffixSUF-exia%20(pathology)%20forms%20the%20names%20of%20functional%20diseases%20or%20of%20conditions%20such%20as%20pyrexia%20or%20cachexia.)*** refers to a condition, a pathology in medical terms. It comes from PIE ***segh*** ( to hold or have) according to Etymonline.

> - (pathology) forms the names of functional diseases or of conditions such as ***pyrexia or cachexia.***

[-exia](https://books.google.it/books?id=UjKPBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT570&lpg=PT570&dq=exia%20suffix&source=bl&ots=A1QEpmwjZ8&sig=_YRZhgTTmf9ArUGAxNUdRHs_Ms4&hl=it&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0CEMQ6AEwCWoVChMIiZSJyOu-xwIVCUkaCh39ngcA#v=onepage&q=exia%20suffix&f=false):

> - condition. (Medical terminology)

***[Cachexia](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Exia&searchmode=none)*** (n.)

> - "bad general state of health," 1540s, from Latinized form of Greek kakhexia "bad habits," from kakos "bad" (see caco-) + **-exia, related to exis "habit or state," from exein "to have, be in a condition," from PIE root *segh- "to hold, hold in one's power, to have"***
> - ***PIE root [segh-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=scheme&allowed_in_frame=0)***  "to hold, to hold in one's power, to have" (cognates: Sanskrit sahate "he masters, overcomes," sahah "power, victory;" Avestan hazah "power, victory;" Greek ekhein "to have, hold;" Gothic sigis, Old High German sigu, Old Norse sigr, Old English sige "victory").

Note that the suffix ***-exia*** is not related to [anorexia](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=anorexia&allowed_in_frame=0) and [dyslexia](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dyslexia%20&searchmode=none) where the suffix is ***[-ia](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ia&allowed_in_frame=0)*** instead:

-ia:

> - word-forming element in names of countries, ***diseases***, flowers, from Latin and Greek -ia, which forms abstract nouns of feminine gender. In paraphernalia, Mammalia, etc. it represents the Latin and Greek plural suffix of nouns in -ium or -ion.

Comment: Sometimes **-ia** also shows up in names of towns, e.g. Mexia, Texas.